# Why might this inner class be a noncompliant MBean?

Tags: java, jmx

It seems that the fact that my class is an inner class is causing the issue, that's my hunch - but basically it's otherwise the usual pattern:

```
public class UserProvisionerProfiler implements UserProvisionerProfilerMBean {

    @Override
    public int getTotalNumberOfUsers() {
        return activeClients.size();
    }
}
```

And the interface (nested in a larger class):

```
public interface UserProvisionerProfilerMBean {

public int getTotalNumberOfUsers();

}
```

Registered in the code:

```
    UserProvisionerProfiler userProvisionerProfiler = new UserProvisionerProfiler();

    MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName name = new ObjectName(userProvisionerProfiler.getClass().getPackage().getName() + ":type=" + userProvisionerProfiler.getClass().getName());

    mbs.registerMBean(userProvisionerProfiler, name);
```

And the error:

```
   1356 [1;31mERROR[39m [main],            UserProvisioner  ; Unhandled exception caught in     main()
javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: MBean class UserProvisioner$UserProvisionerProfiler does not implement DynamicMBean, and neither follows the Standard MBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Class UserProvisioner$UserProvisionerProfiler is not a JMX compliant Standard MBean) nor the MXBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: UserProvisioner$UserProvisionerProfiler: Class UserProvisioner$UserProvisionerProfiler is not a JMX compliant MXBean)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Introspector.checkCompliance(Introspector.java:171)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:317)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:512)
UserProvisioner.registerThisAsMBean(UserProvisioner.java:734)
UserProvisioner.start(UserProvisioner.java:797)
UserProvisioner.main(UserProvisioner.java:844)
```

I've had little success in finding a stricter definition of a compliant MBean short of reading the JMX spec or code, so I'm wondering if I can salvage the inner class or if I have to separate it out, or if there is something else I'm missing.

Comment: Is your inner class static? If it is not, the inner class cannot be constructed without an instance of the outer class. That could constitute non-compliance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to JMX specification a standard MBean must consist of two parts:

1. The MBean interface named MBean
2. The MBean implementation named  and implementing the MBean interface.

Thanks to those restrictions a static inner class can be an MBean implementation if and only if the MBean interface is also a static inner class of the same containing class.